# Angular DELETE API request doesn't clear my cart

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In the cart component of my app I have an "Clear cart" button. I am trying to clear the cart with a API call that sends a delete request to the API.. My compiler isn't showing me any errors and the console of web browser also isn't showing any errors... but when I click the "Clear cart" button nothing happens.. the items stay in my cart...

What am I doing wrong?

here is the code:

***cart.service.ts:***

```
  clearCart() {
    return from(Preferences.get({key: 'TOKEN_KEY'})).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`);
        return this.httpClient.delete<ShoppingCart>(`${environment.apiUrl}cart`, {headers, observe: 'response'});
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err.status);
        if (err.status === 400) {
          console.log(err.error.message);
        }
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.authService.logout();
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', {replaceUrl: true});
        }
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    );
  }
```

***cart.component.ts:***

```
  clearCart() {
    this.cartService.clearCart();
  }
```

***And html file just in case :)***

```
  <ion-button fill="outline" color="medium" slot="end" size="small" shape="round" (click)="clearCart()">
    Clear cart
    <ion-icon slot="end" name="trash-outline"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
```

***Here is the model of cart:***

```
export interface ShoppingCart {
  total_products: number;
  totals: number;
  notes: string;
  shipping_method: string;
  products: Product[];
}
```

Comment: you missing the `subscribe` in `this.cartService.clearCart().subscribe()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to clear the cart, you need to subscribe to the observable that is returned by the `clearCart` method in the `CartService`.

```js
clearCart() {
  this.cartService.clearCart().subscribe(() => {
    // You can update your cart data here
  });
}
```

make sure to update your local cart also after the API called passed.

Comment: I have tried your solution and I get an error 500 response: message: "Too few arguments to function"

Comment: error 500 is `Internal Server Error` make sure you sending all the data you need in order to remove the cart

Comment: There was a bug on my backend :) Now your code works. But i have to manualy refresh my app to see the empty cart... on frontend the the items stay shown... how do clear them out?

Comment: Like you mentioned in your Answer... how exactly do I update local cart after the API cal passed?

Comment: @weinde If the items in your cart are held in an array in the front end, it's just a case of emptying that array once you receive a successful response from your API call.

Comment: @Laurence I have added the JSON of my cart to the question. Perhaps you can provide an example please?

Comment: @weinde How do you display the items in your cart within your template? E.g - In your HTML template if you're displaying the items in your cart with `*ngFor=let item of cartItems`, clearing the `cartItems` array is going to make sure these don't appear on the front end. I would clear the `cartItems` array on a successful response from your delete endpoint :).